# Checking which (if any) string in array is a superstring of another string array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this situation:

```
var eventTypes = ['#course', '#bundle'];
var customEvent = ['#coursebar']
```

I'd like to check whether any of the strings in `customEvent` is a superstring (`startsWith`) any value of the strings in `eventTypes`, and, if so, return the first value that meets this condition.

I have tried with `find` and `includes`, however I cannot seem to make it work like I need, and most of the examples I found were dealing with just one string and an array.

Some expected results to clarify what I need:

```
var eventTypes = ['#course', '#bundle'];

// CASE 1
var customEvent = ['#coursebar'] // should return '#coursebar'

// CASE 2
var customEvent = ['#foo'] // should return undefined

// CASE 3
var customEvent = ['#coursebar, #coursebaz'] // should return either '#coursebar' OR '#coursebaz'
```

**I know this could easily be achieved with for loops, but I was wondering if there was a more concise and modern way of doing it.**

Comment: Just a side-note: Don't discount _for loops_. I have seen (though this may not be consistent) that sometimes modern, chainable, non-mutating, one-line array methods which are good for DX (Developer Experience) can take a lot longer than a _for loop_ (an ancient workhorse by any measure, but spectacularly optimised since it's been around for so long) and consequently not so good for UX (User Experience). I'm all for good DX, but it shouldn't come at the cost of good UX.

Comment: good point, thank you! I am not avoiding them at all costs. In this specific case I bet it should not make much difference in terms of efficiency, but I totally agree with you ;)

Comment: No, I agree with you, @umbe1987 - here it makes no difference to use a chainable array method and you're probably right to do so. I only mention it because I started to learn more about _functional programming_ earlier this year and I - momentarily! - wanted to eradicate all _for loops_ from my code, everywhere... before I learned that one needs to exercise discretion when to ditch them and when to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```js
customEvent.find((x) => eventTypes.find((y) => x.startsWith(y)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Although all other solutions were good, I chose to accept yours because it is the only one that returns exactly one string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array#find` with `array#some` to check if `eventTypes` exist in `customEvent`.

```js
const eventTypes = ['#course', '#bundle'],
  customEvent = ['#coursebar, #coursebaz'],
  result = customEvent.find(event => eventTypes.some(type => event.startsWith(type)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `some` like this:

```
let results = customEvent.filter(evt => eventTypes.some(ty => evt.startsWith(ty))
```

and afterwards you can get any element out of `results` which you want